# is it possible to know which view has opened up the alertview?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have created an alert Dialog. It opens up custom view which has listview and searchview.I need to update the view which has opened up this custom dialog. How can i do it?
What i mean is can i get the view by which has opened up another view? I want to get the view which has opened up another view.

**this is my code :**

```
 public class activitySignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {


              //  For Custom Views...
              private ListView listView;

              //  for Different Methods...
              private ArrayList < ? > GeneralList;
              private ArrayAdapter < ? > GeneralAdapter;

              private SearchView searchView;

              //  Popup view for Selection...
              private AlertDialog builder;

              @Override
              protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

               initView();
              }

              //  Inside context i am passing the context of the view according to switchview...
              //  intentRelatedTasks are for Passing intents...
              //  For showing error there's show Error...
              builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activitySignUp.this).create();
              View custom_view = LayoutInflater.from(activitySignUp.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_view,
               null);
              searchView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
              listView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.list_all);
              searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
              searchView.requestFocus();

              builder.setView(custom_view);

              //  Initializing ArrayLists and Setting them up on Adapters...
              GeneralList = new ArrayList < > ();
              GeneralAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (activitySignUp.this, android.R.layout
               .simple_list_item_1, GeneralList);
              listView.setAdapter(GeneralAdapter);


              listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
              searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
              searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
             }

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
              switch (view.getId()) {
               case R.id.stateInput:


// This is the view from which i am opening up alertdialog, i have plenty of these(TextViews) with different IDs,which opens up same AlertDialog with different listitems... So i want this view to be updated when i open up/ Dismiss alertview...
                getStates();
                break;
              }
             }

             private void getStates() {
              MyAPI.getStates(new Callback < BasicResponse > () {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call < BasicResponse > call, Response < BasicResponse > response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "GetStates");
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful()));
                Log.i(TAG, GsonUtils.toGson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.isSuccessful()) {
                 builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_state));
                 BasicResponse basicResponse = response.body();
                 String res = basicResponse.getResponse();
                 Type listType = new TypeToken < ArrayList < State >> () {}.getType();
                 ArrayList list = GsonUtils.fromGson(res, listType);
                 ArrayList arrayList = updateListAndDropdown(GeneralList, list, GeneralAdapter);
                 Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + arrayList);
                 UpdateTextViewUI(getResources().getString(R.string.select_state), stateInput);
                 builder.show();
                }
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call < BasicResponse > call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, t.getMessage());
               }
              });
             }

             private ArrayList updateListAndDropdown(ArrayList arrayList, ArrayList arrayList_new, ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter) {
              Log.d(TAG, "updateListAndDropdown: " + arrayList_new);
              arrayList.clear();

              if (arrayList_new != null)
               arrayList.addAll(arrayList_new);

              arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              return arrayList;
             }

// This is where i want things to happen. on click i want to update  UI which has opened up my alertdialog.
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
              ViewParent parent = adapterView.getParent();
              AppCompatTextView appCompatTextView = (AppCompatTextView) parent;
              appCompatTextView.setText(GeneralList.get(position).toString());
              builder.dismiss();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please post your code on how you open the dialog, and which view you are trying to update.

Comment: Hello Avi. To try to help you we need some code. If we dont have code to see we can't figure out how to help you. Thanks

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer Please see updated code.

Comment: @Tepits code added please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store lastclicked View that opened up the alert dialog by creating a POJO class which contains a view variable and then get that view wherever you want inside your same activity class using same object.

This is the code for the class :-

```
import android.view.View;

/*

    I am making this class to cache(store) View of last clicked item which has opened up the
    custom fragment dialog in signup view.

 */
public class LastViewClicked {

    private View view;

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

by using setview and get view method you can store and fetch the last clicked item. also if other item enebles popup view then just update it view using setview method. getview method remains the same. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need create an interface and a custom dialog.

I let you an example code here to understand this:

**Interface:**

```
interface OnViewUpdate {
    void updateView();
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnViewUpdate{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyCustomDialog customDialog = new MyCustomDialog(this,this);
        customDialog.showAlert();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateView() {
        //Update whatever you need here.
    }
}
```

**CustomDialog:**

```
public class MyCustomDialog  {
    private Context context;
    private OnViewUpdate callback;
    private AlertDialog builder;

    public MyCustomDialog(Context context, OnViewUpdate callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        //Your code is here, declare whatever you need
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activitySignUp.this).create();
        View custom_view = LayoutInflater.from(activitySignUp.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_view,
                null);
        searchView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        listView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.list_all);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();

        builder.setView(custom_view);

        //  Initializing ArrayLists and Setting them up on Adapters...
        GeneralList = new ArrayList < > ();
        GeneralAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (activitySignUp.this, android.R.layout
                .simple_list_item_1, GeneralList);
        listView.setAdapter(GeneralAdapter);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);

        //In your listview listener you need call to the callback to update the view in the mainActivity.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ViewParent parent = adapterView.getParent();
                AppCompatTextView appCompatTextView = (AppCompatTextView) parent;
                appCompatTextView.setText(GeneralList.get(position).toString());

                callback.updateView();

                builder.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: I have created this viewparent and tried to access it, but the thing is that i am using customview for alertdialog and viewparent will give me LinearLayout, so i cant cast it to AppCompatTextview.

Comment: can't i have a method which tells me that you have clicked this view and onclick of that view you have opened up this alert dialog?